# How do I add a custom action to the user.aspx administration page?

Tags: 2010, custom-actions, user-accounts

I need to add a custom action to the built-in user administration page.

I know how do do a custom action for our own lists, but I can't find any information on how to hook into this page. We need to capture the selection of users and groups, and then display a custom page that takes the id's of the groups and users selected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

UserCustomAction **ScriptLinks** scoped to the SiteCollection will execute on **every** page.

Easy to attach with the SharePoint Editor Chrome Extension

- https://github.com/tavikukko/Chrome-SP-Editor
- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-editor/ecblfcmjnbbgaojblcpmjoamegpbodhd?hl=en

Comment: How would I do this programmatically/by configuration?